# Rspec strong params with merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So i'm trying to write some tests for a project I'm working on.
Controller

```
  def update
    @project = Project.find_by(id: params[:id])
    current_tags = @project.project_tags
    current_tags.destroy_all
    @project.assign_attributes(project_params)
    tags = params[:tags].split(',')
    if @project.save
      tags.each do |tag|
        valid_tag = Tag.find_by(name: tag.strip.capitalize)
        if valid_tag
          @project.tags << valid_tag
        else
          flash[:notice] = "That tag does not exist"
        end
      end
      redirect_to @project, notice: "Project updated successfully"
    else
      flash.now[:errors] = @project.errors.full_messages
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

In my models

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"
  has_many :project_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :project_tags
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :collaborators, through: :collaborations, class_name: "User"

  validates :creator, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :status, presence: true
  validates :skills_desired, presence: true

  def tags_for_edit
    tags.map { |tag| tag.name }.join(', ')
  end

  def collaborators_with_status(status)
    User.joins(:collaborations)
    .select("collaborations.project_id, collaborations.status, users.*")
    .where("status='#{status}' AND project_id=#{self.id}")
  end

  def collaborations_with_status(status)
    Collaboration.where("status='#{status}' AND project_id=#{self.id}")
  end

end
```

The Rspec I'm attempting to write

```
  describe 'PATCH #update' do
    context 'while not logged in' do
      xit 'redirects user back to the root path' do
        get :patch, id: project
        expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end

private

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :start_date, :end_date, :status, :skills_desired, :repo_link).merge(creator_id: session[:user_id])
  end
```

My project factory with Factory Girl

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    creator_id 1
    title {Faker::Hacker.adjective}
    description {Faker::Hacker.say_something_smart}
    start_date {Faker::Date.between(2.days.ago, Date.today)}
    end_date {Faker::Date.forward(20)}
    status 'planning'
    skills_desired 'be smart'

    factory :invalid_project do
      title nil
    end

  end
end
```

And finally the error I'm getting

```
  1) ProjectsController PATCH #update while not logged in redirects user back to the root path
     Failure/Error: let(:project) {FactoryGirl.create(:project)}
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Creator can't be blank
```

So i'm assuming the problem is that in my controller in my strong params I am merging the creator id to the project. I'm not really sure what the correct syntax would have to be to make the test. I've been searching the internet for some time and can't find anything. Would love some help on this one. Thanks

Comment: You should add the project `id` on your `project_params` and you don't need to merge anything since the `project` already belongs to a `creator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the current error your getting

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
    Validation failed: Creator can't be blank
```

is because you have this line here

```
validates :creator, presence: true
```

Because of this you can't create a Project factory without a valid Creator record id assigned AND the Creator record needs to exist first. I would recommend you do something like this for a Creator factory. This way you can be assured there exists a Creator record with a valid id to use in the creator_id attribute of the project record

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :creator do
      some_attribute "some attribute"
      after(:create) do |creator, evaluator|
        creator.projects << FactoryGirl.create(:project, creator_id: creator.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

So after some experimenting and a little help from a friend, I was able to add the collaborator id by doing this in the project factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    association :creator, factory: :user
    title {Faker::Hacker.adjective}
    description {Faker::Hacker.say_something_smart}
    start_date {Faker::Date.between(2.days.ago, Date.today)}
    end_date {Faker::Date.forward(20)}
    status 'planning'
    skills_desired 'be smart'

    factory :invalid_project do
      title nil
    end

  end
end
```

The field that I added was the association

```
association :creator, factory: :user
```

This allowed me to use the association that I set up in my models within the factory. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. @MilesUA your solution worked as well, but the one I managed to come up with helped me keep it to 1 factory. Thanks again